# How to use config value in symfony2 translation?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

Is it possible to use global variable from config.yml in translation file in symfony 2?
If yes, please can you give some example or useful link?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I would like to use some text(example: www.stackoverflow.com) in more translation files. I don't want to pass each time from twig or php this value in translation. Just want to put somehow in translations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15566695/1847340 check out this solution. worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

For injecting a (or all) twig globals into your translations you need to override the translation service. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550002/advanced-customization-of-translations-in-symfony2/15566695#15566695) if you want a detailed explanation. Here is what I did:

Override the `translator.class` parameter (e.g. in your `parameters.yml`):

```
translator.class:  Acme\YourBundle\Translation\Translator
```

Create the new `Translator` service:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator as BaseTranslator;

class Translator extends BaseTranslator
{

}
```

Finally override both `trans` and `transChoice`:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
{
    return parent::trans(
        $id,
        array_merge($this->container->get('twig')->getGlobals(), $parameters),
        $domain,
        $locale
    );
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function transChoice($id, $number, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
{
    return parent::transChoice(
        $id,
        $number,
        array_merge($this->container->get('twig')->getGlobals(), $parameters),
        $domain,
        $locale
    );
}
```

In this example I am injecting **all** twig globals. You can only inject one like this:

```
array_merge(['%your_global%' => $this->container->get('twig')->getGlobals()['your_global']], $parameters)
```

Comment: In symfony 4.2 it seems preferred to use `$this->container->get('twig')->mergeGlobals($parameters)`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow those 2 simple steps:

1. Inject a [Global variable](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html) in all the templates using the twig configuration:

   ```
   # app/config/parameters.yml
   parameters:
       my_favorite_website: www.stackoverflow.com
   ```

   And

   ```
   # app/config/config.yml
   twig:
       globals:
           my_favorite_website: "%my_favorite_website%"
   ```
2. Use [Message Placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#message-placeholders) to have the ability to place your text in your translation:

   ```
   # messages.en.yml
   I.love.website: "I love %website%!!"

   # messages.fr.yml
   I.love.website: "J'adore %website%!!"
   ```

You now can use the following twig syntax in your templates to get your expected result:

```
{{ 'I.love.website'|trans({'%website%': my_favorite_website}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid this step in twig.
In this example I would like to use _my_favorite_website_ directly in translation and call it in twig without passing any value:
`{{ 'I.love.website'|trans() }}`

Comment: Mmmmh I am afraid there is no simple solution to do this. The translation service requires that you pass the placeholder in an `array()` as a second parameter when calling it so it is more a translate service "limitation" than a twig one. You could probably write a twig extension if the placeholder is always the same but that would be a dirty trick...