# Symfony pluralization ignoring floats

Tags: symfony, pluralize

I'm using Symfony Translations ported into my framework. I found this in docs:

```
'{0} There are no apples|{1} There is one apple|]1,19] There are %count% apples|[20,Inf[ There are many apples'

The above string specifies four different intervals: exactly 0, exactly 1, 2-19, and 20 and higher.
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#explicit-interval-pluralization

My problem is that I need to use different plural for `1.5` than I'm using for `1`. How can I do that? When I pass `1.5` as a count parameter, it gets `1` plural assigned.

I thought specifying interval as `]1,something]` would work, but it's basically the same as `[2,something]` according to docs (In that case I don't see a point in using `]1` anyway). How can I cover `1.5` plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Symfony reference, `Interval` (http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Translation/Interval.html ) and TranslatorInterface (http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Translation/TranslatorInterface.html), accept an `int` value, so I think what you're trying to achieve is not possible.

You may, however, override the Translator service and implement your logic. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566695/5248767) for details.